# Identify what value of $x$ may have issues with cancellation error

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

I am leaning numerical analysis and getting a hard time to understand cancellation error. For example, suppose we have $\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)$, this is the same as $\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)$. Suppose we just need 6 digits when we compute $\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)$. I have tried to MatLab to look at 0.01,0.5,100,1000, etc, I don't see that how to compare $\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)$ and $\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)$ because the results from MatLab are the same.

---

Can someone tell me how to identify when cancellation error exists? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe MatLab can be induced to work to limited precision. If not, use a cheap calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem will arise when $x$ is huge. In this case $\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)$ is a subtraction of nearly equal numbers which will give instability. In particular, when $x$ is huge, $\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)$ is very nearly $1/x$; the true error in that approximation is less than $1/x^2$. With the second version, you do get very nearly $1/x$, with the first you do not. Try it out with $x=10^{14}$.

Unfortunately this example is not perfect because when $x$ is large, the second implementation suffers from another source of floating point error, namely "swamping". This can be very clearly seen when $x=10^{16}$, where both methods (in double precision) give zero. In the second implementation this happens because 10^16+1==10^16, in the sense of floating point arithmetic. A better implementation for large $x$ would be log1p(1/x).

Comment: Is there a way to determine when cancellation exist without computing any numbers?

Comment: @Simple It will happen whenever $|x-y|$ is much smaller than $|x|$ and $|y|$.

Comment: See my answer for a systematic method to analyze such error behaviour, including both kinds of numerical instability that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer does not really address the question of how to systematically determine when cancellation error occurs. Here's a reasonably accurate method.

We assume that the machine computes at a fixed floating-point precision with relative error $ε$. Let "$[r]$" denote $\def\rr{\mathbb{R}}$"$\{ x : x \in \rr \land |x| \le r \}$" for any $r \in \rr$, for convenience. Then to determine the error in any computation, simply multiply each intermediate value by $ρ=(1+[ε])$, and remember that errors do not cancel out!

For the example in question (where $x \in \rr_{>0}$):
$\def\wi{\subseteq}$
$\def\comp{\rightsquigarrow}$
$\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}$

> $\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)$
>
> $\ \comp \ln((x+1)ρ)ρ - \ln(x)ρ$   [Note that we cannot 'factorize out' $ρ$ because it is a set!]
>
> $\ = (\ln(x+1)+\ln(ρ))ρ - \ln(x)ρ$
>
> $\ \wi \ln(x+1)ρ + \ln(ρ)ρ - \ln(x)ρ$
>
> $\ = \ln(x+1)-\ln(x) + \ln(x+1)[ε] + \ln(x)[ε] + \ln(ρ)ρ$.   [Error term signs do not matter.]
>
> [Accurate iff $\max(|\ln(x+1)|,|\ln(x)|)[ε] \ll \ln(x+1)-\ln(x)$.]
>
> $\ln(\lfrac{x+1}{x})$
>
> $\ \comp \ln(\lfrac{(x+1)ρ}{x})ρ)ρ$
>
> $\ = ( \ln(x+1)-\ln(x)+\ln(ρ^2) ) ρ$
>
> $\ \wi (\ln(x+1)-\ln(x))ρ + 2\ln(ρ)ρ$
>
> $\ = \ln(x+1)-\ln(x) + (\ln(x+1)-\ln(x))[ε] + 2\ln(ρ)ρ$.
>
> [Accurate iff $2\ln(ρ)ρ \ll \ln(x+1)-\ln(x)$.]

As you can see, it shows both rigorously and clearly how the errors arise in both computations, and we can even determine exactly what $ε$ we need to obtain the desired precision in the answer. For example, to get a desired relative error of $δ$ we need $2\ln(ρ)ρ \le (\ln(x+1)-\ln(x))δ$, which as $ε \to 0$ and $x \to \infty$ is approximately equivalent to $2ε \le \frac1x δ$, which shows that using the Taylor expansion $\ln(1+\frac1x) = \frac1x - \frac1{2x^2} + \cdots$ is strictly better as $x \to \infty$.